Renormalization from cohomology point of view
In order to construct a Euclidean quantum filed theory one usually needs to take care of the renormalization problem. Let us consider a simple model like $\phi^4$ in dimension two. In this case just the Wick renormalization will be sufficient. (Indeed, the renormalized field will coincide with the fourth Hermite polynomial, which is a martingale.)
I wonder if there is any work to study the renormalization procedure from a cohomology/homology point of view?

The question is rather vague as posed. What do you imagine the "differential" would be?

In the action of a EQFT theory model like $\phi^4$, there is Laplacian. To make sure that it is injective, let us consider $(1-\Delta)$, which corresponds to a massive scalar filed. In this case, we know that its resolvent, which is the covariance of the corresponding Gaussian measure is diverging near the origin, for example in d=2, it diverges logarithmically. I imagined Laplacian to be a legitimate differential operator here.

If the Laplacian is your "differential", then it's cohomology is not going to take you very far and its relation to renormalization would be questionable. Now, this interpretation of what you meant might be purposely obtuse, but perhaps you can see that the vagueness of the question leaves enough room for interpretation to make it rather dull. Elaborating on what you had in mind would only improve the original question.

Costello's book Renormalization and Effective Field Theory develops a cohomological approach to renormalization.

I think Costello uses cohomology on the $\phi^4$ example, even though it is not needed as Igor said, as a pedagogical warm up for the case of renormalization in the presence of gauge symmetry, in the BV formalism. For this topic, indeed the book by Costello would be a good reference, and there is also a book by Kasia Rejzner " Perturbative Algebraic Quantum Field Theory, An Introduction for Mathematicians".
